# path relative to cpp not working directory

Tags: c++, path

I am working on some C++ code, that mainly provides a class for two other projects that share it but also includes a small program so that it can be used from the command line if needed. The class has to load some resources, that are written to several files in a resources folder. The path to these files is of course hard coded into the program, since I don't want any client using the class having to worry about loading those resources, other than calling an init method. When I compile the project on its own, with the hardcoded `fopen("resources/myresource.dat")` it works as expected, but when it is included in another project, the whole thing is typically placed into a separate subdirectory with only the header included as `#include "subdir/myclass.h"`. In this case the hardcoded paths are invalid as the working directory is one folder higher.

How can I make sure the path to the resources folder is always valid, regardless of the path of the include?

Comment: You *could* do this by calling an operating-system-specific function to determine the path of your EXE, and then using relative paths based on that location. But a *better* option is to embed those resources into your executable, and then load them that way. Again, platform-specific, but this way you won't have to worry that the `resources` folder is missing or moved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I make sure the path to the resources folder is always valid, regardless of the path of the include?

It's not anyhow related to the include's path.

What you actually need is an installation routine, that provides you with a environment variable like `$MYAPP_RESOURCE_PATH` and having that expanded instead of your hardcoded path `"resources/myresource.dat"`.

You can retrieve the environment variable's value with the [`getenv()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/getenv) function.